# How to move character/object using button in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working in xcode and developing an arcade like game. I can't seem to figure out how to move my character right only on the x-axis when the button labelled right is pressed. I have figured almost every other way to make the character move but with a button which makes this even more frustrating, and to most of you, this is probably a really simple answer. I'm writing in objective-c. If you could show me the code I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: how is your button created? programmatically or with interface builder?

Comment: This is EXTREMELY Vague!  what elements are you using, UIImageViews, OpenGL, etc.....???

Comment: Sorry Guys, I wasn't thinking. I am not using cocos2d just regular. The image I want to move is called box and is in a UIImageView, and the button to move it is called rightButton, and is a UIButton. Thanks for your quick responces, sorry for my lack of details.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this is just using regular frameworks and not something like cocos2d. You need to update the frame or center of the object!

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = self.myObject.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 20; //however many pixels to the right..
    self.myObject.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a character that is being displayed in a UIImageView, UIView, or some other subclass of UIView you simply can update the frame by how far you want the character to move.

```
- (IBAction)move {

int distanceRight = 5.0;

theView.frame = CGRectMake(theView.frame.origin.x + distanceRight, theView.frame.origin.y, theView.frame.size.width, theView.frame.size.height);

}
```

No you can wrap theView.frame call in a UIView animation block to have it animate to the new position rather than just jump.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{
                        theView.frame = CGRectMake(theView.frame.origin.x + distanceRight, theView.frame.origin.y, theView.frame.size.width, theView.frame.size.height);
                     }];
```